# Not picking the browser which is specified in terminal command

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def setup(browser):
global driver
# if browser == 'firefox':
#     driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Drivers/geckodriver.exe")
if browser == :
driver= webdriver.Ie(executable_path="C:/Drivers/msedgedriver.exe")
else:
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Drivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Drivers/geckodriver.exe")
return driver

def pytest_addoption(parser):
parser.addoption("--browser")

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def browser(request):
request.config.getoption("--browser")

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

After adding return to Browser function, it is working now.

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def browser(request):
**return** request.config.getoption("--browser")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).